# I want to click the checkbox to display the database filed values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to click checkbox to show the data what i want fetch through ajax call, but it is showing database all data automatically show whats the problem please find out and help me (just i want ajax call)

**Controller**

```
//This is my controller
public function laptops()
{
$this->load->model('feature_model');
$filter = array(
    'price' => $this->input->get('price'),
    'name' =>$this->input->get('name')
);
$data['laptop'] = $this->feature_model->laptops_m($filter);

//echo json_encode($this->feature_model->laptops_m($filter));
$this->load->view('feature/checkbox',$data);
} 
//This is my model
 function laptops_m($filter = null){
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('mobile_phones');
   // $query = $this->db->get('laptop_notebook')->result();
   // return $query;
    if($filter['name']){
        $this->db->where('name', $filter['name']);
    }
    if($filter['price']){
        $this->db->where('price', $filter['price']);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;

}
//This is my view
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="acer">  


<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="lenovo">    

<input type="checkbox" name="price" value="1000">   



 <table>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($laptop as $laptops_all) { ?>
            <tr>

                <td><p>Laptop <?php echo $laptops_all->name ?> </p>
                </td>


            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Ajax script:**

```
//  This is the ajax script function
<script>
$("input[checkbox]").change(function(){
               $.ajax({
            url: localhost/ci35/feature/laptops,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    $("tbody").empty();
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+
                    "Laptop "+element.brand+""+
                    "</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to get data to display from `GET` array here:

```
$filter = array(
    'price' => $this->input->get('price'),
    'name' =>$this->input->get('name')
);
```

But your `GET` array is empty because of you don't send any data with your `json` request. From jQuery documentation:

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

So you should iterate over checked `checkboxes` and add it's values to array. Then send this array via `data` property of `ajax` request.

Comment: please answer me anyone

Comment: As I said there is problem on JS side not on PHP side. And I have told you what you should do.

Comment: how am rectifing that

Answer (score 0):

Try this..add  class="searchType" to html checkbox element, then in jquery

```
$('.searchType').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
       if(this.checked){
         $.ajax({
            url: localhost/ci35/feature/laptops,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    $("tbody").empty();
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+
                    "Laptop "+element.brand+""+
                    "</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        }); 
     }
   });
```

as you are printing the data through success ajax call, no need to use foreach again in view.

Also in your controller, you have to print json data.

```
    public function laptops()
    {
    $this->load->model('feature_model');
    $filter = array(
        'price' => $this->input->get('price'),
        'name' =>$this->input->get('name')
    );
    $data['laptop'] = $this->feature_model->laptops_m($filter);

    echo json_encode( $data['laptop'] );
   // $this->load->view('feature/checkbox',$data);
    }
```

Comment: where is the load view in controller

Comment: not working same output it displays all at a time not showing after click the checkbox